# WordPress Uninstall.php

Tags: wordpress, uninstallation

I keep finding conflicting ways to write an uninstall.php file for your plugin. I know how to delete_options, I'm just not sure If the beginning of my uninstall.php is correct. I've found two articles that say to do it differently:

Codex:

```
//if uninstall not called from WordPress exit
if ( !defined( 'WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN' ) )
exit (); 
delete_option('example');
```

and alternate source (wptuts):

```
if(defined('WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN') ){  

  //delete options, tables or anything else  

}
```

So which is the correct way? I'm leaning towards the wptuts way, but only because it seems to make a bit more sense to me.
Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the same thing.

```
IF exists DO something

==

IF not exists DO nothing
```

That `exit()` should be indented or written like

```
if ( !defined( 'WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN' ) ) {
    // not defined, abort
    exit ();
} 
// it was defined, now delete
delete_option('example');
```

---

See [Uninstall script for a plugin in Multisite](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/80350/12615).